# No route matches [GET] "/session.json" rails + backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, session, backbone.js

I am having problems with my sessions in rails, I am also using backbone.js - it seems that rails is looking for a route called /sessions.js, in addition, when I look in console I can see in Network response `NoMethodError in SessionsController#create`. At this point a user can not be logged in on the site, but I can see the session ID in console.

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html #:json

  def new

  end

   def create
      user = User.find_by(email: params[:sessions][:email])
          if user && user.authenticate(params[:sessions][:email])
                session[:current_user_id] = user.id
                log_in user  

                @notice    = true 
          else
                 @notice = false
          end

            respond_to do |format|
                  format.html {render(:text => "not implemented")}
                  # format.js
              end
    end 
# Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

      # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
    # def remember(user)
    #     user.remember
    #     cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    #     cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    # end

    #destroys user's session - logout
    def destroy
        log_out if logged_in?
        redirect_to root_path
    end 
end
```

Here is my sessions helper:

```
    module SessionsHelper

    # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # returns current user to be easily accessed later
  def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  # is the user even logged in?
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

end
```

Not sure if this is part of the problem, but here is my view in Backbone which uses session:

```
    App.Views.LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#login-view',
  events: { 'submit form':   'authorize' },

  authorize: function () {
    // if (this.submitButton.hasClass('disabled') && !(this.form.data('user-authorized') === true)) {
    //   return false;
    // } else {
    //   this.submitButton.addClass('disabled');
    // }
        var self = this,
         attrs = {
          email: this.emailField.val(),
          password: this.passwordField.val()
        };

    User.authorize(attrs, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { self.loginFailure(); }
      else { self.loginSuccess(); }
    });
    return (this.form.data('user-authorized') === true);
  },

  loginSuccess: function () {
    this.form.data('user-authorized', true);
    this.form.submit();
  },

  loginFailure: function () {
    this.$el.animate({left: '-=20'}, 100);
    this.$el.animate({left: '+=40'}, 100);
    this.$el.animate({left: '-=40'}, 100);
    this.$el.animate({left: '+=40'}, 100);
    this.$el.animate({left: '-=20'}, 100);
    this.emailField.focus();
  },

  initialize: function () {
    this.template = HandlebarsTemplates['login'];
    this.render();
    this.form = this.$el.find('form');
    this.emailField = this.$el.find('#login-email');
    this.passwordField = this.$el.find('#login-password');
    this.submitButton = this.$el.find('#login-button');
  },
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template);

    $('#login-view').append(this.$el);
  }

});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Inside NETWORK tab, in console:

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    <div class="source " id="frame-source-0">
      <div class="info">
        Extracted source (around line <strong>#9</strong>):
      </div>
      <div class="data">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="lines">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <pre class="line_numbers">
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
<span>9</span>
<span>10</span>
<span>11</span>
<span>12</span>
              </pre>
```

Comment: Which line is the NoMethodError on? Can you post the console log?

Comment: updateing my question

Comment: Here is an example of what is in that file, it is a massive file and most of it looks like this, the only line i thought relevant was the first one?

Comment: I think your session is nil.  I think it is kind of weird that you would be passing the session through params either way.  can you console log params?

Comment: i tried hitting binding.pry and this what is get:

Comment: Started POST "/session.json" for ::1 at 2015-08-26 14:38:20 -0400
Processing by SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"email"=>"clone@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'

Comment: You can see in the last code you posted that the params doesn't have a 'sessions' key, so params[:sessions][:email] isn't working. Does params[:email] work instead?